# Rake gets aborted with error: no such file to load -- openssl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rvm, bundler

I keep getting openssl issues on my Mac. I am completely perplexed by the error messages when I try to issue rails tasks. What might be the issue? 
I definitely have openssl on my machine because when I type it in the terminal, it opens an openSSL> session.

Every time I try the following: `RAILS_ENV=development rake db:migrate`
I get the below error:

```
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- openssl

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

When I type the above with --trace option, it shows an error which is listed below.

When I try to launch rails server by typing `rails s` I get the below error:

```
   $> rails s
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/net-ssh-2.6.6/lib/net/ssh/transport/openssl.rb:2:in `require': no such file to load -- openssl (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/net-ssh-2.6.6/lib/net/ssh/transport/openssl.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/net-ssh-2.6.6/lib/net/ssh/buffer.rb:2:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/net-ssh-2.6.6/lib/net/ssh/buffer.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/net-ssh-2.6.6/lib/net/ssh/transport/algorithms.rb:1:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/net-ssh-2.6.6/lib/net/ssh/transport/algorithms.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/net-ssh-2.6.6/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:7:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/net-ssh-2.6.6/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/net-ssh-2.6.6/lib/net/ssh.rb:10:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/net-ssh-2.6.6/lib/net/ssh.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/net-ssh-gateway-1.2.0/lib/net/ssh/gateway.rb:2:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/net-ssh-gateway-1.2.0/lib/net/ssh/gateway.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/capistrano-2.14.2/lib/capistrano/configuration/connections.rb:2:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/capistrano-2.14.2/lib/capistrano/configuration/connections.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/capistrano-2.14.2/lib/capistrano/configuration.rb:5:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/capistrano-2.14.2/lib/capistrano/configuration.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/capistrano-2.14.2/lib/capistrano.rb:3:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/capistrano-2.14.2/lib/capistrano.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /Users/imtiazahmad/scripts/xxx-patchtrack/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rebuilding ruby with ssl support:

```
port install openssl +universal
rvm install 1.9.2 --with-openssl-dir=/opt/local
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to use `sudo` for rvm and I think people generally prefer Homebrew over Macports as it's more up-to-date and does not require installation as a privileged user.